# Maximize the result for given array of values

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of values example:

`[[x,y], [x1,y1]]` each element holds two values, the `amount` we need to pay at 0th index and `items` we can collect at 1st index. Also, I have a `budget` of z.

I want to find the maximum number of items I can collect using this budget.

Here is my program:

```
public static long solve(List<List<Long>> arr, long z) {
    arr.sort((a, b) -> {
        int z1 = Long.compare(a.get(0) , b.get(0));
        if(z1 == 0) {
            z1 = Long.compare(b.get(1) , a.get(1));
        }
        return z1;
    });
    
    long total = 0;
    long result = 0;
    for(List<Long> list : arr) {
        if(total + list.get(0) <= z) {
            total += list.get(0);
            result += list.get(1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct approach for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a variant of the [0/1 knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/).

- The cost of each item is the "weight"
- The budget becomes the "total weight"
- The number of items you can collect becomes the "value" for that item

**Edit**

If the total weight is large and the traditional dynamic programming approach can't be used, you can redefine the states to get a solution, as demonstrated [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-with-large-weights/).

Comment: In many approaches I see in the solutions they declare an array like `int []dp = new int[W + 1];` but in my case the W which is budget is a long value. So I am not able to create a array like this.

Comment: @learner add the relevant constraints to the question. Edited the answer